# ImGui, with SDL2 Renderer, what is the point of the three separate NewFrame functions?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, imgui

I'm trying to set up ImGui with the SDL2 backend and software renderer. In the provided example (`./examples/example_sdl2_sdlrenderer2/main.cpp`) there are these three calls at the beginning of every rendering cycle:

```
        // Start the Dear ImGui frame
        ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer2_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();
```

If I comment out any one of these calls, the program crashes. If I reorder them, it crashes for some orders and works fine for other orders. So why are these three even separate calls? What is the difference between them, and why do I need all three?

I expected there to be at least some documentation on this question (specifically, on the subject of what order I'm supposed to call them in, which depends on which etc.), but there is nothing about them. There are general documentation pages for `ImGui::NewFrame()`, but it's as if the other two do not exist at all.

Additional questions:
Are there any circumstances in which it makes sense to use only one or two of them?
Is one ordering of them preferable to another, at least sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

ImGui and its backends are modular. `ImGui::NewFrame();` is to be called regardless of the used backend.

`ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame();` is for SDL2 backend, but SDL2 supports multiple different rendering methods (OpenGL, Vulkan, builtin renderer).

`ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer2_NewFrame();` is for SDL2's builtin renderer.

Comment: I pretty much got that from the structure of the header files. Still, the question remains: is there a reason for the fact that I can (and should) manually call all three? And also for the order I call them in, etc. Does it ever make sense to call one of them super early in the timeframe, and the other two later?

Comment: @СергейМакеев *"reason ... manually call all three"* Same reason why you have to write `.c_str()` every time you pass a `std::string` to ImGui, or why ImGui doesn't provide RAII wrappers over their widgets: the developer thinks that the manual way is the best way, for better or worse. *"order I call them in"* If the examples don't show otherwise, I wouldn't mess with the order.

Comment: Does that mean that, if I am writing my own wrapper around this system, I can just combine these three into one function and forget about it? How can I be sure I'll never need them separately?

Comment: @СергейМакеев I would combine them. If the examples don't call them separately, then you probably don't need to either.